# How do I speed up the network discovery of windows servers from my mac?

Tags: macos

I just bought my first MacBook Pro. One frustration I have is accessing my shared windows-based network assets. I have two servers on the network, but they seem to take forever to be discovered by my MBP.

Use Case:

1. I open my MBP
2. Once connected to WiFi, I open Finder and then Go > Network
3. I wait and wait and wait and wait for the windows-based network assets to be discovered

I'm not sure how long it takes because I usually just go about doing other things then check back. I think it could take up to a half hour though (more/less). Sometimes, even when I can see the server, it takes an unacceptably long time to connect to it.

Is there any way to improve this? 
Is the problem a mac/pc thing?

Comment: I would love to hear other people's experience of this -- i find the same problem, and want to know if it's the way i have my network set up, or if it's something about Mac networking.

Comment: Same problem for me. I don't wait to 'discover' the device, but connect to it directly. (Under the menu Go > Connect to Sever), but even then sometimes it takes a long time.

Comment: Same here. I've noticed that on my new MBP with 16GB RAM, this has been less of an issue, but it's still much slower than I'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Only using `Finder` the workaround that works for me in macOS 10.14.5 is:

1. In Finder **menu bar** select ***Go > Connect to Sever...***
2. Use your windows machine IP address to make a ***Connect***